# expect: How to cancel `expect_before` and `expect_after`?

Tags: match, expect

It seems that using `expect_before` or `expect_after` once, they are applied to any `expect` following, causing unexpected timeouts.

So I wonder: How can I cancel a preceding `expect_before` or `expect_after`?

What I had tried so far without success (it still seems to match `" "`) was:

```expect
expect_after
expect_after { }
```

Or did I misunderstand the concept completely?

Trying to control a shell-like program, this is what I did (roughly):

- As the program echoes its input (`$cmd`), use `expect_before $cmd`
- As the program will output a prompt (`$prompt`) after the command, use `expect_after $prompt`
- Use `expect` to match the actual command output

However there are two exceptions:

1. When asking for a password, there won't be `$prompt` when expecting password input; thus I want to cancel the `expect_after`.  As the password isn't echoed, I want to cancel the `expect_before` when sending the password, too.
2. When quitting the program, there won't be a prompt after executing the `quit` command, so I want to cancel the `expect_after`.

Comment: could you post a [repro] which can demo the problem?

Comment: Note, you might be able to do away with `expect_before` by switching off the echo done by the pty created by spawn. `set stty_init "-echo"` before the spawn can change the stty settings applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding Tcl braces. They are not special syntax, they are just a quoting mechanism -- they're like shell single quotes: no interpolation within. So `expect_before { }` means you're expecting a single space, and no action is specified.

I think, to cancel an expect before, you use `expect_before` with no arguments.

Use `expect_before -info` to see the current status.

---

To ignore the sent $cmd, I think you want

```
expect_before -ex $cmd {exp_continue}
```

You need to redo this every time the `cmd` variable changes.